# Web site added to home screen takes to long to show updates

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, homescreen

I made a site using React and i added it to the home screen using Chrome and it works fine, but my problem is, when make a change to it, if i access it on the web it shows right away the changes, but on the home screen "App" it takes a long time for the changes to be visible.

Is there a way to force the updates, maybe delete the cache or force a ETag change?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@Franmcod, could you try the following:

Push F12 or Ctrl+Shift+J to "Open Developer Tools" on Windows, then you can right click on the refresh icon and select 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'. this should remove what's cached in chrome and load the newer web page after you make the changes. for Mac use: Cmd+Opt+I.

Adam